# Passing list of dynamically created dropdownlists to controller in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, dropdown

I have a MVC5 project with a form where the user can click and add new dropdowns dynamically, it uses select2 and ajax to get the posible values and filter...

```
//ViewModel
 public class MyViewModel
    {        
        public List<string> Skus { get; set; }

       //Tried public List<List<string>> Skus { get; set; } w/no success
    }

//MVC Razor view 
 <div id="SkuContainer">
Product variations: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Skus, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Select", new { multiple = "true", @class = "Skus", @id = "Skus1" })
</div>
 <input id="btnAddSku" type="button" value="Add variations" class="btn btn-primary" />
 <input id="btnRemoveSku" type="button" value="Remove variations" class="btn btn-danger" />

....
$(document).ready(function () {....
$("#btnAddSku").on("click", function () {
            var i = 2;
            var dropdown = "<select data-val='true' class='Skus' id=Skus" + i + " name=Skus style='width:1000px' multiple> </select >";
            var VariationContainer = "<div id='variationsdiv'><br/> Product variations: " + dropdown + " </div>";            
            $("#SkuContainer").append(VariationContainer);
            i++;
        });

...
//Controller:
public ActionResult Confirm(MyViewModel model)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(model.Skus ) // I get all the selected values, it works but I can't diferenciate each dropdown because of how the model is structured. 
}
```

How can I set the model and the view to get a list of lists of selected values so I can diferentiate each dropdown?

Thank you

Comment: `I get all the selected values, it works but I can't diferenciate [sic] each dropdown because of how the model is structured. ` -- I think this needs to be fixed in the Model.

Comment: Thank you Robert, I also tried to create a class like: 
public class Skus
    {
        public List<string> Sku { get; set; }
    }
then in the viewmodel:

public List<Skus> Skus { get; set; }

but dont know where to set this in the razor view @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Skus, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Select", new { multiple = "true"})

it comes emtpy